# How to close office 365 taskpane from plugin javascript code?

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

I am creating an Office 365 plugin for outlook using NodeJS and javascript... I use OfficeJS library to interact with Outlook. My plugin appears in the Outlook taskpane. I want to have button in my plugin HTML. When clicking on that button the taskpane must be closed. Anybody knows how ? thank you !

Answer (score 6):

This feature is not available yet, but you will be able to add it into your add-in soon. As of Office.js API level 1.5 you will be able to call the method "closeContainer()". Preview documantation is available at [Office.context.ui.closeContainer()](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/1.5/Office.context.ui.html#closeContainer)

EDIT:

[Office.context.ui.closeContainer() method](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.closecontainer?product=outlook&version=v1.5?product=outlook) is available at Mailbox 1.5 level API. The supported host is limited to Outlook.

Currently there is no support for any other hosts to open and close taskpain. If you have strong requirements for this feature please consider up-vote the [uservoice suggestion](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15114417-support-for-hiding-showing-task-pane-through-the-o) for Office developers.

Comment: This is only for Outlook though. How to do it in any other office addin?

Comment: @Erndob I have edited my answer to include the information you are asking about.

Answer (score -1):

I

```js
  Office.context.ui.closeContainer()
```

have tried some code but this code works for me

Comment: This is the same solution as the first example in the other answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33945427)