# How to configure lable. icons and URL in VSTO word addin

Tags: vsto, office-addins, word-addins

I have VSTO word addin and I have put a button in the ribbon and a label (company name).

On button click, I get selected text and pass this selected word as a queryparam to my application as below: [www.myapplication.com?selectedtext=](http://www.myapplication.com?selectedtext=) [getselectdwordfromword]

We have few clients and all have a different application name.

So how can the client set his application URl and label (company name)?

Is there any way so we can provide configurations and client changes configurations based on their requirements before installing VSTO in their system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've used SQL Server CE in these instances. You can embed the database file in the add-in with the .DLLs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please share a link for reference? If we embed the database, Will every client set his value, URL and label (allocation name)?

Comment: Here's a project where I use SQL Server CE to store values. There are 2 .net versions in C# and VB .net.  https://github.com/Excel-projects/Script-Help

Comment: If you only need one set of values, you can always use the application settings to hold the values.

Comment: @aduguid, I am not sure about the above link how to store value in DB and read it. It is not clear my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a custom UI for the add-in installer where your customers can enter the required application URL and company name. So, at runtime you could read such values from the windows registry or any other place where the add-in installer could write down these values after installing. The [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) article describes all the required steps for creating MSI installers.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your response. If I use Windows Installer, How the client can set URL/application name? I could not find this in the above links.

Comment: You need to create a custom UI in the add-in installer. For example, you can add a new page with two textboxes where users could enter the required information during installation.

Comment: Hi, ye that we have already done but Client wants its configure (Admin person can configure) so all its users can use the same name instead of individual user go and update settings. In the scenario you mentioned and we are already using, Every individual users of client need to do these setting. Is there any way so admin person do these settings and indivusal person can use those? Thanks in advance

Comment: In office 365 Addin, We have menifiest.xml where one admin can URL and name and after that can share with all his users but in office 365 addin we can not use runtime URL to open inside taskpane.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361368/how-to-close-office-365-taskpane-from-plugin-javascript-code/42370019

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130614/close-add-in-task-pane-from-button-inside-add-in